# Showing fatal PHP errors in GAE appengine logs

Tags: php, google-app-engine

In local dev environment I see php errors from a call to an external REST service (payment gateway). This is dumped on my browser as expected and shows up in the log console (GAE launcher) - no problem.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Paybrkr\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'Invalid integer: 997.001' in E:\code\apper\application\libraries\Paybrkr\lib\ApiRequestor.php:98 Stack trace: #0 ...
```

In production, users just see a blank/500 error which I understand is by design. However the error appears nowhere in the prod logs. I would expect under Critical or Error log level. Any special settings required in php.ini for GAE?